# Receiving 403 Forbidden Response after TLS-DSK Lync-SIP handshake

Tags: authentication, sip, lync

I have some code that is sending an INVITE to a lync address (test1@lync2013.example.com). I  initially receive a 401 Unauthorized from the server (as expected).  I then perform a TLS-DSK handshake as documented here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff530353(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff530353%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and this completes.

However, I am now stuck receiving a 403 Forbidden response when trying to INVITE (that is, sending my 4th INVITE - the first 3 are used for the TLS-DSK handshaking), and in the ms-diagnostics header in the response has:

```
ms-diagnostics: 4005;reason="Destination URI either not enabled for SIP or does not exist";source="LYNC13.test.example.com"
```

The test1 user definitely does exist (I can call it from another Lync client) and an the Control Panel I have the user set for "Enterprise Voice" telephony which I believe is correct if the client is set up to be able to receive external SIP calls.  Am I missing any more configuration?

If it helps, my SIP domain is lync2013.example.com, my AD domain is test.example.com and my Lync server FQDN is LYNC13.test.example.com.

Many thanks in advance to anyone able to help (or is seeing the same problem specifically on Lync 2013).  I am in the process of configuring Lync 2010 that I will be able to check against.

Thanks again,

Simon Tolham

Comment: Are you doing this auth in Java with jain-sip ?